# I want to access my System default Ringtone's name

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I am a newbie in kotlin/android development ,  I want to access my System default Ringtone's name and display it in a String , How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
data class NotificationSoundDataModel(
    val soundName: String? = null,
    val soundUri: String? = null
)

private fun getRingtoneList(): ArrayList<NotificationSoundDataModel> {
    val notificationList = ArrayList<NotificationSoundDataModel>()
    val manager = RingtoneManager(context).apply {
        setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    }
    val cursor: Cursor = manager.cursor
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        val title: String = cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX)
        val uri: String =
            cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.URI_COLUMN_INDEX) + "/" + cursor.getString(
                RingtoneManager.ID_COLUMN_INDEX
            ) + "?title=" + cursor.getString(
                RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX
            )

        notificationList.add(NotificationSoundDataModel(title, uri))
    }
    return notificationList
}
```

Ref: https://medium.com/@rathorerahul586/android-change-notification-sound-93eb4fd4ece5